# rake db:migrate errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

Below is the `database.yml`. I have installed `postgresql` as required. I have created username and password as in `database.yml`.
I encounter following error while I run `rake db:migrate`:

```
maringanti-mbp:xpm smaringanti$ rake db:migrate
==  AddAutoToProjectPerson: migrating =========================================
-- change_table(:project_people)
   -> 0.0008s
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

divided by 0/Users/smaringanti/xpm/db/migrate/20150601054955_add_auto_to_project_person.rb:33:in `/'
/Users/smaringanti/xpm/db/migrate/20150601054955_add_auto_to_project_person.rb:33:in `calc_effort'
/Users/smaringanti/xpm/db/migrate/20150601054955_add_auto_to_project_person.rb:19:in `up'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:534:in `up'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:574:in `exec_migration'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `block in migrate'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `migrate'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:709:in `migrate'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `block in migrate'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `each'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `migrate'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**And this is my migration file**

```
class AddAutoToProjectPerson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :project_people do |t|
      t.integer :auto_effort
    end
    pp_list = Array.new
    current_id = nil
    ProjectPerson.where("percent_effort IS NULL and finish IS NULL").order(:user_id).each do |pp|
      if pp.user_id != current_id
        puts current_id
        unless current_id.nil?
          calc_effort(pp_list, current_id)
        end
        current_id = pp.user_id
        pp_list.clear
      end
      pp_list << pp
    end
    calc_effort(pp_list, current_id)
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :project_people do |t|
      t.remove :auto_effort
    end
  end

  def self.calc_effort (pp_list, current_id)
    current_total = ProjectPerson.where("percent_effort IS NOT NULL and finish IS NULL").where(user_id: current_id).group(:user_id).order(:user_id)
      .select("SUM(percent_effort) as assigned_effort").first
    value = current_total.nil? ? 100 : 100 - current_total.assigned_effort
    value = 0 if value < 0 
    value = value / pp_list.size rescue 0
    for item in pp_list
      item.auto_effort = value   
      item.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this happened when i did rake db:migrate

Comment: Show the migration that it is crashing on.

Comment: You're dividing my zero in `20150601054955_add_auto_to_project_person.rb` so what does that look like?

Comment: can you add your migration file here??